# Do I need special primer for red(ish) paint?

Tags: paint, primer

I am getting ready to paint my living room using Behr's *Glowing Firelight* (S-G-200):

[image]

My building sidekick suggested not to use the regular Killz2 primer but some special gray primer for red(ish) paints.  I am posting here to confirm his suggestion and open a discussion for second opinions.  Which specific primer would be the best for this paint?

Answer (score 1):

You should have your Kilz 2 tinted the same color as the topcoat. Most places will do that for free.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the primer that you feel best meets the purpose of the room.  Have it tinted grey.  The grey tint allows the red to show faster - less coats.  If you want me to give advice on specific primer then I would say what kind of room it is and if there are any special conditions.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't really answer my question -- it merely recycles it.